# NoClassDefFoundError java gradle

Tags: java, gradle

gradlew build works fine `\gradlew build -> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s`  but
`java -jar build\libs\gradle-tutorial.jar` shows `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.casper.sdk.CasperSdk
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
```

I searched similar issue but still cannot understand how to resolve this.
Can you please help take a look? Thank you in advance!

Java file

```java
package com.jh;

import com.casper.sdk.CasperSdk;


public class GradleTutorial {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws Throwable {
        final CasperSdk casperSdk = new CasperSdk("http://16.162.124.124", 7777);
        try {
            String nodeStatus = casperSdk.getNodeStatus();
            System.out.println(nodeStatus);
        } catch ( Exception exp ) {
            System.out.println("Exception while fetching node status");
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.jh.GradleTutorial'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
    implementation 'network.casper:casper-java-sdk:0.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the full error? See ["Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) this may be of use to you

Comment: @EwanBrown
This is the full error
```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.casper.sdk.CasperSdk
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
```